# How to initiate a global method that can be accessed by all controllers in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, global, pojo

I would like to initiate a simple POJO that generates an array of random Strings when initiated (or when the Spring Boot application starts). This array of Strings has to be shared across every controller in the Spring Boot application, and it cannot be different for different controllers. The class and methods (of this shared POJO) are internal to a Spring Boot application and are accessed by calling the getters in the controller methods (only).

Furthermore, I would like to avoid using the application.properties. The best solution would be java-only (no database such as H2 or offloading the POJO onto a file). Also, using the sessions will not help.

Something like this would help:
http://www.masterspringboot.com/security/authentication/securing-spring-boot-with-in-memory-basic-authentication

How can I accomplish such a design ?

My idea is to simply use a micro-service and launch it separately, but I would like to confirm if there is something else I can do within the single Spring Boot application.

Comment: I don't get it, can you update your question exactly what you want to do? the link is not related to it, or let us know if it is.

Comment: No, I can't tell exactly what I want to do, because it is too complex. Sorry. I will look around for a solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the solution was to use the in-memory provided by the [mapDB](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapdb/mapdb), and generate all the data during the spring-boot initiating itself...

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapdb/mapdb

The source code example can be found using the search engines...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a singleton class that holds your values:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataHolder dataHolder = DataHolder.getInstance();
        String[] arr = dataHolder.getArr();
    }
    
}


class DataHolder {
    private static DataHolder instance = null;

    private String[] arr = new String[10];

    public static DataHolder getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new DataHolder();

        return instance;
    }

    private DataHolder() {
        fillArray();
    }

    private void fillArray() {
        // use this method to fill your array
    }

    public String[] getArr() {
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that is not the answer (or the level) I am looking for. It has to be within the spring boot framework and called from within a controller. It has to be an in-memory storage.

Comment: Do you mean you want to make a `@Component`? There is no internal storage in spring boot. Either you hard-code the strings in the application, save it to a file or save it to a database. Every other option is that you lose the data.

Comment: The @Component would be the solution if I didn't have to initiate it in multiple controllers. the problem is, every time I do it, the random number generator creates different numbers. It has to be consistent over the multiple controllers (global)... so if there is a way to do it, then it is a solution I need. Otherwise, I will simply run a separate micro-service.

Comment: OK I found a solution: https://www.baeldung.com/mapdb